# Why is my professor using two getchar();?

Tags: c

Why is my prof using two getchar(); at the end of our C program tutorials?

And what is the "better way" for this?

Comment: Did you ask in/after class?

Comment: Go ask him; maybe he's trying to be smart.

Comment: I think a better way would be a self-modifying program that inserts as many calls to getchar to the end of the program as there are unread characters in the input buffer. You know, sometimes two ain't enough, either. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best better way is not to add any code to try and keep the console window open: start your program right from the console window.

If you must start your program from the IDE and want the program to not terminate before the user presses Enter, one single `getchar()` should do it.

The second best better way to make the program terminate after the user presses a key, is to always make sure there are no inputs pending and use one single `getchar()`.

The reason your teacher uses 2 `getchar()`, I guess, is that there is already a character in the input buffer from previous inputs. To consume all characters from the inputs, up to and including the ENTER, this is usual:

```
int ch;
/* ... */
printf("Press Enter"); fflush(stdout);
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) /* void */;
```

Comment: This is a standard C idiom. I believe it works in C++ too, but may not be idiomatic in that language.

Comment: [Veganaize](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039027/veganaize) suggested `puts()` instead of `printf(); fflush(stdout);`. The reason for my choice is to keep the blinking cursor on the same line as the "Press ENTER" text. Note that `puts()` automatically adds a newline making the `fflush()` call redundant.

Comment: @Veganaize: if you **always** keep track of newlines in input (using, eg, the method in this answer), there is never a need for two `getchar()` to ignore two ENTERs: there is never more than one in the input buffer. Best method overall for dealing with user input starts with `fgets()` anyway.

Answer (score 23):

He is waiting for user input so that you can see the output to the program, otherwise it will just complete and the output will not be visible (depending on the OS). Take it out and give it a try.

Comment: Also remember this answer as you move through your studies - "Take it out and give it a try" is a very handy tool in what we do.  Don't be afraid to tinker sometimes.

Answer (score 16):

He wants the console to stay open and wait for the user to press a key. I think to remember that depending on what happens in your professors program above the "getchar()". There might still be something in the buffer, so he added a second "getchar()". Not exactly the most elegant way to solve the problem.

Edit: Here is a little example. There is still a remaining "\n" in the buffer from the "scanf()" If you add a second "getchar()", you get the expected result. You have to flush the buffer before the "getchar()".

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
int input;
scanf("%d", &input);
printf("The input is %d\n", input);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Edit 2: Here is a solution taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/7312/).

```
int c;
printf( "Press ENTER to continue... " );
fflush( stdout );
do c = getchar(); while ((c != '\n') && (c != EOF));
```

Comment: And I thought everyone else already knows this, you seem the only one here that understands the buffer issue.

Comment: @abyx I thing the buffer issue is pretty known, but shouldn't flushing the buffer be preferable? Or maybe even system("PAUSE");?

Comment: system("PAUSE") is platform depended and works only under windows.

Comment: I've never seen a program that had to wait for a key at the end of its output that had to be platform independent. It's nearly always some throw away program or something written for academic purposes.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you shouldn't use system("PAUSE") to test your code. But since we used to pass our programs around in school, I just wanted to point it out so there won't be any surprises when you give it to somebody who doesn't run windows.

Answer (score 5):

The reason a lot of beginners feel it necessary to put *two* `getch` calls in their code is that one single call often doesn’t work.

The reason for that is that `getch` fetches the next keyboard input from the input queue. Unfortunately, this queue gets filled whenever the user presses keys on the keyboard, even if the application isn’t waiting for input at that moment (of if it isn’t reading the whole input – see Lulu’s answer for an example). As a consequence, `getch` will fetch a character from the input queue *without* waiting for the *next* key press – which is really what the programmer wants.

Of course, this “solution” will still fail in a lot of cases, when there’s more than just one character in the keyboard queue. A better solution is to *flush* that queue and *then* request the next character. Unfortunately, there’s no platform-independent way to do this in C/C++ to my knowledge. The conventional way to do this in C++ (sorry, my C is limited) looks like this:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
```

This simply ignores all available input, effectively clearing the input queue. Unfortunately, this code doesn’t always work, either (for very arcane reasons).

Comment: What about this here for flushing?

void clearStdin() {
  int c;
  while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
};

Comment: @Christian It’s entirely possible that this works but I guess it could fail for the same reason that the above C++ code sometimes fails.

Comment: The question is about `getchar`, not `getch`

Comment: @M.M And seven years old.  Back then it was apparently usual to post answers in slightly unrelated languages. Anyway, the bulk of the explanation is the same, just the code needs adjusting.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is my prof using two getchar(); at the end of our C program tutorials?

Assuming you have something like

```
int main ( void )
{
    int     input;

    scanf ( "%d", &input );

    printf ( "The input is %d.\n", input );

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Two because `scanf` won't return until after an enter is pressed, but there will be the '\n' from the enter and any other characters you have entered in the input buffer.

So if you run the above and input `1234`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program will pause after printing `The input is 1234.` until you then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. The first `getchar` reads the `'\n'` associated with the first <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you input something else, such as `1234`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, the program will not pause, as first `getchar` will read the space. Two `getchar`s might not be enough, and you've interspersed the code for printing the response into the code for handling the input.

> And what is the "better way" for this?

There are various standard ways of reading input in C. There are also platform specific ways of ignoring text in the input buffer, but you shouldn't need to do that if you use `fgets` to read a line of input instead of `scanf` to read some input from the last line entered.

`fgets` ( read input until '\n' or end of file ) followed by `sscanf` ( parse a string for input ) is safe from buffer overruns, and will absorb any extra input and line terminating '\n':

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int     input;
    char    buf[16] = "";

    fgets ( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );

    sscanf ( buf, "%d", &input );

    printf ( "The input is %d.\n", input );

    fflush ( stdout );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Flushing `stdout` after the `printf` isn't normally needed for terminal IO, but can be if you're piping it to a disk ( typically when you're logging a crashing program it will lose the most interesting bit just before the crash if you don't flush ).

Because `fgets` reads up to and including the end of the line, there are no characters left in the buffer so you only need one `getchar`, and slightly awkward input such as `1234`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't cause the program to terminate without pausing.

However, most of the time you don't need to wait after running a console application - on Linux or other Unix systems you typically have a console open and run the program there, after which control returns to the shell. On Windows, IDEs such as Visual Studio typically [run the program and pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103402/how-does-vs-compile-console-applications-to-show-press-any-key-to-continue/1103445#1103445) it using something like:

```
 "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c ""...\ConsoleApplication1.exe"  & pause"
```

Or you can open cmd.exe and run it from there, or you can run it with a .pif shortcut and set the checkbox it not to close the console on exit, or you can create a batch file which runs it and pauses.

You really only need to make the program pause itself if you're on Windows and you're using a debugger to run it and you haven't set any breakpoints.

Answer (score 3):

to pause the (probably) commandline program. he is using two, because using only one didn't work and he probably doesn't know why..

find him a better solution to do this (and not std::cin) and you'll be the hero of the day.

Comment: yes i am trying to find this solution :) he said he would cover it later in the semester but i want to find out now.

Comment: well, first of all, he is doing the 'trick' because the buffer (which getchar() uses) might already contain a char, skipping the first getchar() (or at least not pause on it). you could perhaps empty the buffer first? or use a different method for pausing (not System("sleep")!)

Answer (score 1):

Probably to keep the output window open when you run the program from the IDE.

...why there are two there is beyond me though.

Answer (score 1):

It is a naive solution to the unused buffered input problem. Your prof recognises the problem, but it seems does not know how to solve it properly.

If you use formatted input, only characters entered that match the format specifier are used. So if for example the last input requested a decimal integer using %d, you might enter at the console:

`123<newline>`

The formatted input will consume the "123", leaving the `<newline>` buffered. An unformatted input such as getchar() will consume that and return immediately. Since this is not what you want, your prof has used the "just add another getchar() kludge". This works only if the user enters the expected input. A hamfisted typist might type:

`123w<newline>`

Now the first getchar() gets the 'w', the second gets the `<newline>`, and your program terminates before you intended it to, and in a GUI environment, if the terminating process owns the window it is running in, then the OS closes it.

A more robust solution is to repeatedly call getchar() until the `<newline>` is found:

```
while( getchar() != '\n' ) { /*do nothing*/} ;
getchar() ; /* wait */
```

Of course if the previous input was a character, you need to check it was not already a `<newline>`:

```
while( ch != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ) { /*do nothing*/} ;
getchar() ; /* wait */
```

Rather than putting the flush loop at the end just before the 'wait' input call, it is better to perform the buffer flush after every input that requires it. This is because that is where you know you need it, and how it should be coded. I tend to write wrapper functions for the input types I need.

Comment: The explanation is pertinent, but your solutions are not *robust*: you should also check for `EOF`, otherwise a premature end of file will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @chqrlie : Only 8 years to spot that!

Answer (score 0):

`getchar();` at the end of the program creates a "Press any key to continue" situation. I'm guessing that he likes hitting any key twice.

Comment: I don't think, that he likes to hit keys twice, I think he realized that sometimes it doesn't work when he puts just one getchar(). See my example.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a remaining "\n" from the buffer so that the app closes.

Comment: Wouldn't the app also close, if there was still something in the buffer?

Comment: isn't that why he does it twice?

Answer (score -3):

Because one hit of the "enter" button generates **two** characters on Windows, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). At least it used too, long time ago in a galaxy far far away ...

Comment: No, that’s got nothing to do with it.

Comment: stdin is opened as a "text" (as opposed to binary) stream meaning that you only read '\n' when the enter key is hit.

Comment: - And even if pressing enter generated two characters, you would only need to wait for the first before terminating the program.

Comment: Well, the world wasn't always perfect :)