# Usage of two gets() in C++

Tags: c++, getchar, gets

I am learning about classes in C++. I made a simple program using the concept of classes. In the program I need the person to enter the details of the book. Here is that function:

```
void Book::add(){
cout << "Enter name of Book: ";
gets(book_name);gets(book_name);
cout << "\n\nPlease enter the book id: ";
cin >> book_id;
cout << "\n\nThank you the book has been added.";
total++;
input = getchar();
getchar();
}
```

Notice in the third line I have to use two gets to get the user input. If I use one gets
[this is the output. It just skips the gets statement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpN9V.png) Similarly at other places also I have to use two getchar statements. I was able to find the answer for that on SO itself. Ex [Why my prof. is using two getchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432989/why-is-my-professor-using-two-getchar). I couldn't find the answer for two gets statements, though. [Here is the complete code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5635050/) in case it is required.

Comment: Remember that `gets` is a C function using `stdio`. Don't mix C++ stream input from `std::cin` with input from C `stdin`.

Comment: Refer to `gets` manual. NEVER use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have a trailing `new line` (from <kbd>Enter</kbd>) character remaining on the stream that is not read by the first read operation. So the first `gets(book_name)` will read that and continue to the next request for input.

use `getline` to remove any remaining offending input from the stream.

```
void Book::add(){
    string garbage;
    getline(cin,garbage);  // this will read any remaining input in stream. That is from when you entered 'a' and pressed enter.
    cout << "Enter name of Book: ";
    gets(book_name);
    getline(cin,garbage);  // this will read any remaining input in stream.
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter the book id: ";
    cin >> book_id;
```

---

Anyways just use the safer way of reading input from streams

```
cin >> book_name;
```

instead of `gets`. Then you will not have such problems.

---

if you want to read space separated inputs in to one string the use [**std::getline**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) (*like I did for garbage above*)

```
std::getline(cin,book_name);
```

Comment: I think the second getline has to be removed from your code. With it, it doesn't ask for book_id after entering book_name

Comment: @Vijay wouldn't there be a remaining `new line` character after the user enters the `book_name` and presses enter?

Comment: Right, I understand. Thanks for your reply.

About your edit: "cin >> book_name;" accepts only 1 word of a multi word string. A book name can have multiple words. That's why I used gets

Answer (score 1):

`cin` and `cout` are from `<iostream>` and gets comes from `<cstdio>`. It's not good idea to mix those two if you don't exactly know how those two work and what is the difference.

Better idea is to use `cin.getline()`

```
cin.getline(char* s, streamsize n );
```

The second parameter is the maximum length of the input.