# How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?

Tags: c++, console, exit, terminate, c++-faq

Lately, I've been trying to learn C++ from [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/). Unfortunately whenever I try to run one of the code samples, I see that program open for about a half second and then immediately close. Is there a way to stop the program from closing immediately so that I can see the fruits of my effort?

Comment: Are you double-clicking the executable?  Are you working in Windows?  Why aren't you working from the Command shell and typing in the commands as you want them executed?

Comment: @S Lott: Because if you push the "Go" button in your IDE you don't need to bother with a console.

Comment: You should consider getting a good book from which to learn C++.  Websites are good resources, but are no match for a good introductory text.  There's a definitive list of C++ books here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Billy If pressing the Go button closes the app when it terminates, you are using the wrong IDE.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I agree that it sucks but that is Visual Studio's default behavior.

Comment: @Billy Really? well things have gone backwards in VS land. I haven't used it since VC++ 6.0, but in that version, the IDE handles keeping the console open for you.

Comment: Asked and answered previously here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902261/is-there-a-decent-wait-function-in-c , though this one has a better title.

Comment: @Neil... it depends whether you are debugging or not... if not debugging it'll keep it open for you.  And I bet there is some setting for this as well, but I don't feel like digging for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing console window from closing on Visual Studio C/C++ Console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**Edit:**  As Charles Bailey rightly points out in a comment below, this won't work if there are characters buffered in `stdin`, and there's really no good way to work around that.  If you're running with a debugger attached, [John Dibling's suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately/2529936#2529936) is probably the cleanest solution to your problem.

That said, I'll leave this here and maybe someone else will find it useful.  I've used it a lot as a quick hack of sorts when writing tests during development.

---

At the end of your `main` function, you can call [`std::getchar();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar)

This will get a single character from `stdin`, thus giving you the "press any key to continue" sort of behavior (if you actually want a "press any key" message, you'll have to print one yourself).

You need to `#include <cstdio>` for `getchar`.

Comment: This is probably the better of the two answers right now, but I would probably put a comment next to that to tell why you're actually doing it in real code. +1.

Comment: Another variant of this sort if to "#include <conio.h>" and use _getch().

Comment: `getchar` does not solve the problem - or only in limited circumstances, at least. It reads a char from `stdin`, but if there are already characters buffered from stdin the program will carry on without waiting regardless of whether you print a prompt or not.

Comment: @Charles:  A good point.  Ignoring until `\n` is a partial solution, but won't help if more than one line of input is buffered.  I do not know of a standard C++ way to clear everything from an input stream.  :-/

Comment: @James: Old, but how about `std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());`? Got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer/538629#538629).

Comment: @GMan:  I don't think that actually works:  the streambuf probably isn't the only buffer between the input device and `cin`; the OS is probably doing other buffering in the background and there is no standard way to inspect that buffer.r

Comment: @James: `while (std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()) std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());`? :S This should really be simpler.

Comment: @GMan:  It depends on how buffering is handled by the system.  One case where that solution will fail:  the OS has its own buffer that is used when `cin.rdbuf()` is full.  You check `in_avail()`; it's full and greater than zero so you call `ignore(in_avail())` and clear the buffer; you check `in_avail()` again and it is now zero and you break out of the loop.  But, meanwhile, you've typed stuff in and the OS hasn't started putting new characters into `cin.rdbuf()`.  I think it's entirely dependent upon how the system buffers stdin; I'm not all that familiar with how modern systems do that.

Comment: [I do so little work with console input and output, I just don't know much about the details of this.  And, if it were simpler, it would be C# :-P  (I kid, I kid!  Sort of...)]

Comment: One option I use alot is `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` with `#include <limits>`.

Comment: @Xeo:  That works unless there are multiple lines of data buffered in stdin.

Comment: @James: Really? I always thought it ignores `'\n'` times `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`... Seems I still know little 'bout the standard library.

Comment: @Xeo:  It ignores characters until it has read N characters (`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` in your example) or it reads the sentinel value (`'\n'`), whichever comes first.

Comment: @James: You're right, but wouldn't a simple `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())` be sufficient then? The default delimiter for ignore(...) is EOF. Of course it does not work if you have EOF in the stdin buffer, but usually that shouldn't happen? EDIT: Screw that, I just thought that over..

Comment: Please don't do this. :( It's not part of your program's function to do this.

Comment: @nabulke is much easier in case you are using VS IDE, else system("pause"); is right answer

Answer (score 143):

If you are using Visual Studio and you are starting the console application out of the IDE:

pressing **CTRL-F5** (start without debugging) will start the application and keep the console window open until you press any key.

Comment: Starting the console out of the IDE? How and why would you do that?

Comment: Excellent, it worked.  Why is this not the default behavior of Visual Studio?

Comment: I also thought that was the way to do it, until today, when I build a simple console program and the above method did not work :(

Comment: Is there a version of this _with_ debugging?

Answer (score 136):

The solution by James works for all Platforms.

Alternatively on `Windows` you can also add the following just before you return from `main` function:

```
  system("pause");
```

This will run the `pause` command which waits till you press a key and also displays a nice message `Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: That sounds like a Rube Goldberg variation of a solution.

Comment: @Dave Van den Eynde: It's also quite common and comes standard in the boilerplate code in DevCPP. +1

Comment: @Dave on the other hand it does make it clear that this is just a bodge for an example, while std:getch could be accidentally left in real code.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid solution for those on Windows. Whilst not ideal, it does work

Comment: Easiest, quickest, solution. Just what I needed

Comment: I found this useful with Visual Studio since CTRL-F5 would close the console if I needed to enter an input value from the command line.

Comment: @eaglei22 it's platform specific and it's functionality might change if MS ever decide to change what `pause` does, or even remove it.

Comment: @thecoshman Ah okay, that makes sense. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 86):

If you are using Microsoft's Visual C++ 2010 Express and run into the issue with **CTRL+F5** not working for keeping the console open after the program has terminated, take a look at [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/868551df-9d87-43cb-b24b-d8665a2ae646).

Likely your IDE is set to close the console after a CTRL+F5 run; in fact, an "Empty Project" in Visual C++ 2010 closes the console by default. To change this, do as the Microsoft Moderator suggested:

> Please right click your project name and go to Properties page, please expand Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System, please select Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in SubSystem dropdown. Because, by default, the Empty project does not specify it.

Comment: What if it's not a console app?

Comment: @Mr.Underhill This will *only* work if you launch without the debugger (Ctrl+F5).

Comment: Apart from being the only non-hack solution, this is also the only way to see prints from main stack objects destructors.

Answer (score 20):

I usually just put a breakpoint on `main()`'s closing curly brace.  When the end of the program is reached by whatever means the breakpoint will hit and you can ALT-Tab to the console window to view the output.

Answer (score 16):

Why not just run the program from a console ie run the program from cmd.exe if you're using Windows. That way the window stays open after the program finishes.

[EDIT]: When I use KDevelop4 there is a fully fledged instance of Bash (a Linux CLI) running in a tab at the bottom of the IDE. Which is what I use in these sort of circumstances.

Comment: Because if you are using an IDE you don't generally use a console. You push go, the program runs, and that's it.

Comment: +1: Blindly using IDE isn't really all that helpful.  Using a console to run console applications seems appropriate.

Comment: Any competent IDE will keep the console on screen when the app terminates - Code::Blocks for example does exactly this.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Visual Studio does not, and I suspect that's what the OP is using. Though I agree with you that it should.

Comment: If VS can't be configured to keep the window open, then use the console itself.

Comment: @Billy: VS does too, press Ctrl+F5.  If you use Start Debugging (F5), it assumes you actually want to debug the program.

Comment: @nobugz:  Unless I've screwed something up on my installation, which is quite possible, that is not the behavior in Visual Studio 2010 and I would have sworn that it's not the behavior of 2008.  Is that a configurable option, do you know?

Comment: @James: not that I'm aware of, I've never seen or heard it not work.

Comment: @nobugz:  I figured it out.  To get the window to stick around, you have to have /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE on the linker command line.  The documentation says that this is the default if `main` is defined, but if I don't explicitly set it on the command line, VS kills the window when the application exits.  *sigh*

Comment: @James: that is required to get a console window in the first place.  That in turn requires main() instead of WinMain(), not the other way around.  I'm a bit lost...

Comment: @nobugz: If you start from an "Empty Project" instead of a "Win32 Console Application" the subsystem is not explicitly set in the project properties. If you define `main` in the project, the linker by default uses the CONSOLE subsystem. When debugging or running, you'll get a console window. However, unless you explicitly specify CONSOLE as the subsystem in the project properties, Visual Studio will not keep the console window open. I always start from an empty project and I rarely change individual project properties, so I've never seen the console window stick around. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @James: If Visual Studio doesn't know you've got a console application, then Windows itself is allocating the console when the app starts, in which case it is also destroyed when the app exits.

Comment: James is right. I had the same problem with a "project from existing code" and setting the subsystem (which was blank) fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

Before the end of your code, insert this line:

```
system("pause");
```

This will keep the console until you hit a key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cout << "Please enter your first name followed by a newline\n";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Hello, " << s << '\n';
    system("pause"); // <----------------------------------
    return 0; // This return statement isn't necessary
}
```

Comment: It also printed "Press any key to continue . . ." for me.

Comment: You could do `system("pause > nul");` if you want it to pause but not output text to console saying "Press any key to continue . . ."

Answer (score 9):

Call `cin.get();` 2 times:

```
    //...
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0
}
```

Comment: what if we need another cin.get() for getting for example some string inside array before this? It's not work in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

If you run your code from a competent IDE, such as [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), the IDE will manage the console it uses to run the code, keeping it open when the application closes. You don't want to add special code to keep the console open, because this will prevent it functioning correctly when you use it for real, outside of the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

I just do this:

```
//clear buffer, wait for input to close program
std::cin.clear(); std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
std::cin.get();
return 0;
```

Note: clearing the cin buffer and such is only necessary if you've used cin at some point earlier in your program.  Also using std::numeric_limits::max() is probably better then INT_MAX, but it's a bit wordy and usually unnecessary.

Comment: It works, but the return 0; won't execute if I use this code.

Answer (score 3):

Okay I'm guessing you are on Windows using Visual Studio... why?  Well because if you are on some sort of Linux OS then you'd probably be running it from the console.

Anyways, you can add crap to the end of your program like others are suggesting, or you can just hit **CTRL + F5** (start without debugging) and Visual Studio will leave the console up once complete.

Another option if you want to run the Debug version and not add crap to your code is to open the console window (Start -> Run -> cmd) and navigate to your **Debug output directory**.  Then, just enter the name of your executable and it will run your debug program in the console.  You can then use Visual Studio's attach to process or something if you really want to.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following at the end of your program. It will try to capture some form of user input thus it stops the console from closing automatically.

```
cin.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually debugging your application in Visual C++, press F5 or the green triangle on the toolbar. If you aren't really debugging it (you have no breakpoints set), press Ctrl+F5 or choose Start Without Debugging on the menus (it's usually on the Debug menu, which I agree is confusing.) It will be a little faster, and more importantly to you, will pause at the end without you having to change your code.

Alternatively, open a command prompt, navigate to the folder where your exe is, and run it by typing its name. That way when it's finished running the command prompt doesn't close and you can see the output. I prefer both of these methods to adding code that stops the app just as its finished.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines before any `exit()` function or before any `return`s in `main()`:

```
std::cout << "Paused, press ENTER to continue." << std::endl;
cin.ignore(100000, "\n");
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the first line works but pressing enter does nothing

Answer (score 2):

simply

```
#include <cstdio>

    int main(){
        // code...
        std::getchar();
        std::getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

for some reason there is usually 1 character possible to read with getchar already in stdin when you run a program. so the first getchar reads this character, and the second getchar waits for user (your) input before exiting the program. And after a program exits most of terminals, especially on Windows close terminal immediately.
so what we aim to is a simple way of preventing a program from finishing after it outputs everything.
Of course there are more complex and clean ways to solve this, but this is the simplest.

Comment: Please add at least a short explanation of why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio (and only Visual Studio) the following code snippet gives you a 'wait for keypress to continue' prompt that truly waits for the user to press a *new* key explicitly, by first flushing the input buffer:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

_tprintf(_T("Press a key to continue "));
while( _kbhit() /* defined in conio.h */ ) _gettch();
_gettch();
```

Note that this uses the `tchar.h` macro's to be compatible with multiple 'character sets' (as VC++ calls them).

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include "stdafx.h"` & `system("pause");` just like the code down below.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello programmer!\n\nEnter 2 numbers: ";
    int x, y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    int w = x*y;
    std::cout <<"\nyour answer is: "<< w << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `system` is declared in `<cstdlib>`, not `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Also `system("pause >nul")` is better because it doesn't print out "Press any key to continue . . ."

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea to **yeh** answer, just minimalist alternative.

Create a batch file with the following content:

```
helloworld.exe
pause
```

Then use the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

See if your IDE has a checkbox in project setting to keep the window open after the program terminates. If not, use `std::cin.get();` to read a character at the end of main function. However, be sure to use only line-based input (std::getline) or to deal with leftover unread characters otherwise (std::ignore until newline) because otherwise the .get() at the end will only read the garbage you left unread earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(2);
```

If you clear the buffer first it won't be a problem when you read the next one.
For some reason `cin.ignore(1)` does not work, it has to be 2.

Comment: 2 is sometimes also not enough (when there are more key strokes queued). The correct way is to ignore as many characters as are in the queue. To with, `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail`. Not some magic number like 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just create a batch file. For example, if your program is called helloworld.exe, some code would be:

```
@echo off
:1
cls
call helloworld.exe
pause >nul
goto :1
```

Comment: This is a bad solution AND it's bad batch code. A better solution would be to just use `system("pause >nul")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows, then you can do `system("pause >nul");` or `system("pause");`. It executes a console command to pause the program until you press a key. `>nul` prevents it from saying `Press any key to continue...`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting a breakpoint at the last return 0 of the program. It works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How this doesnt provide answer? Im in exactly same situation like author of a question and this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used `cin.get()` and that is worked but one day I needed to use another `cin.get([Array Variable])` before that to grab a ling string with blank character in middle of. so the `cin.get()` didn't avoid command prompt window from closing. Finally I found Another way: 
Press **CTRL+F5** to open in an external window  and Visual Studio does not have control over it anymore. Just will ask you about closing after final commands run.

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting a `getchar()` function at the end. But it didn't work. So what I did was add two `getchar()` functions one after another. I think the first `getchar()` absorbs the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you press after the last data input. So try adding two `getchar()` functions instead of one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pressing the run button, press CTRL and F5 at the same time, it will give you the press any key to continue message. Or type "(warning use this only for testing not actual programs as an antiviruses don't like it!!!!)" at the end of your main function but: (warning use this only for testing not actual programs as an antiviruses don't like it!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

just use cin.ignore() right before return 0; twice

```
main()
  {
  //your codes 

  cin.ignore();
  cin.ignore();

  return 0;
  }
```

thats all

Comment: I normally do this something like this.
cin.ignore();
cin.get();

Comment: Could you elaborate why it's needed twice?

Answer (score 0):

you can try also doing this

```
sleep (50000);
cout << "any text" << endl;
```

This will hold your code for 50000m, then prints message and closes. But please keep in mind that it will not pause forever.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a problem, not so obvious.  Somehow I had added a debug breakpoint at the very last line of my program. `}` Not sure how I did that, perhaps with an erroneous mouse click while jumping between different screens.  I'm working in VS Code.

And when I go to debug, the system jumps immediately to that breakpoint.  No error message, no interim output, nothing.  I'm like, how did the program rush thru all my set breakpoints?  This took too long to figure out.

Apparently the system sees that last line breakpoint as a "first" stop.  The simple fix?  Delete that breakpoint, doh! (insert forehead slap here.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this problem(more like a feature and not a problem) after I setup visual studio for OpenCV C++ development. I must have enabled automatic closing of the console. When running normal C++ programs that return an output in the console it closed instantly.
I found a solution in another question and it worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084067/15012520

Go to `Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> General >> Automatically close the console when debugging stops.`

Answer (score -1):

You can even declare an integer at the beginning of your `main()` function (say `int a;`) and put `std::cin >> a;` just before the return value. So the program will keep running until you press a key and enter.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do set a variable for x then just type this in before the return 0;

```
cout<<"\nPress any key and hit enter to end...";
cin>>x;
```

Answer (score -2):

Include `conio.h` and at the end of your code, before `return 0`, write `_getch();`

Answer (score -3):

You could also stick

```
while(true)
    ;
```

or

```
for(;;)
    ;
```

at the end.

Comment: -1 Busy spins are evil.  They consume your CPU cycles and accomplish nothing.  If you are going to do something like this, at least put a call to pause inside the loop body to yield the majority of your cycles.

Answer (score -3):

Start in debug mode, run code with F5
to stop your console app, don't click on red cross but press CTRL-break
and you'll hit all breakpoints in the end of your program.

Answer (score -5):

simply put this at the end of your code:

while(1){ }

this function will keep going on forever(or until you close the console)  and will keep the console it from closing on its own.