# preventing an exe file from closing

Tags: c, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

I created an exe file in c. When I run it command prompt opens and then closes quickly and I cannot see the output. The program takes no runtime values from users. It reads data from a file. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: This has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725823/how-do-i-get-the-screen-to-pause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902261/is-there-a-decent-wait-function-in-c , not to mention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193469/how-to-make-visual-studio-pause-after-executing-a-console-app-in-debug-mode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900666/system-calls-in-c-and-their-roles-in-programming .

Comment: Oh, but those are C++ questions!

Answer (score 12):

Run it natively from the command line.

Let's say that your file is in C:\awesomeness.exe

Open the cmd, type `cd C:\` and then type `awesomeness.exe`

Comment: Thanks, really helped out reading a error. and it's an awesome answer.

Comment: what if an exe (precompiled) file is closing at it own? this way does not prevent it from closing,

Answer (score 2):

One classic way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("hai");
    getchar();
}
```

This will wait for keypress at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Windows?  If so, a quick and dirty way is to use the system() function in stdlib.h (make sure you include it) to execute the PAUSE command in the command prompt.

```
system("PAUSE");
```

Comment: [Please, no.](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, hit `CTRL + F5` instead of `F5` in order to run your program.

Comment: But in this way you lose the debugging facilities; a better approach, in an IDE, is to add a breakpoint just before the end.

Comment: Needlessly break?
I suppose that works fine until user passes out the program as an exe and people run, whoops... what did it say?

Answer (score -1):

Using 'system("pause");' before ending main() is the most common method.

```
int main() {
    ...
    ...
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `system("pause");` is the most common method [to avoid](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html).

Comment: by count of small assignment programs out there, it may in fact be the most common method, whether it is good or you like it or not. However, some feel a crusade is better than a simple correction. How about saying the following "system() is inefficient, x is better and does the same thing" It in fact gets to the point much quicker in almost the same amount of letters.