# "Dont let cmd window to close automatically" -how can i do this?

Tags: c, windows, cmd

see i have compile one c program and prepare one a.exe

Now when ever i **click on a.exe**

cmd windows opens

a.exe run

and automatically close that windows.

**What should i do in program or anywhere so this way after running that a.exe that cmd windows don't close automatically**.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Hang on while I find it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: @Mysticial and Seth Carnegie If in that duplicate is ther any other solutin rather then using getchar() or makibg .batch file?? then please let me know and vote to close my question

Comment: @Mr.32 there are 4 ways that I know of: `cin.get()` or equivalent, `system("PAUSE");`, running from the command line, or the batch file.

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148248/preventing-an-exe-file-from-closing: The first comment has a full list of them. I'm disturbingly surprised at how long it took to find this one. So I can't the OP for not being able to find it before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a batch file with the following content:

```
a.exe
pause
```

Then start the batch file

As an alternative you could add a line to your C program that prompts the user for input before exiting.

Comment: thanks i am going with bach file

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`getchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) which will read a single character from `stdin`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  // getchar() waits until its able to read a character from stdin
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `system("PAUSE");` just before the `return` in your `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your program from the command prompt:

Press winkey + R to open up the `run` prompt, and type in `cmd`. Then press enter. Now navigate to the directory where your program is by using the `cd` command, and run it from there.

Alternatively, you can add this to the end of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
     // ...    
     getchar();
     return 0;    
}
```