# C++ project in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, console

I'm create c++ empty project in visual studio 2010. Write simple program (e.g. hello world) and run it. But console window immediately closed! What to do?

Comment: wait for input, say `std::cin >> somevar;`

Comment: it's a bad decision. Maybe somewhere in the settings of the project should indicate something...but I do not know what and where

Comment: you mean you don't like to wait? Then just start a console application as a... console application perhaps. In my experience IDEs frequently do the wait for you when not debugging. Don't remember about VS really

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately/2529803#2529803

Answer (score 3):

It "disappears" because your program runs to an end and you don't tell the console to "stay".

There are at least **two ways** to solve this problem.

Press keys **ctrl** + **F5** to start your program if you don't wanna debug your program. It will hold the console window for you until you press any key.

If you wanna debug your program with **F5**, you can explicitly "hold" the console as:

```
// trivial, just to hold the console for you
std::cin.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't have anything that would temporarily stop the program from going any further. Such as waiting for some simple input. You could add that. A "press any key to continue" if you will. 
Or just launch your application from within a cmd window. It will still immediately terminate, but at least the window will stay opened.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a console program under the debugger (for example by pressing F5) the program will not stop unless it hits a breakpoint.

If you run the console program *not* using the debugger (such as with Ctrl-F5), it will stop when the program ends and display a "Press any key to continue . . ." prompt.

One easy workaround is to set a breakpoint at the end of `main()` or wherever else might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint on the last line of `main`.  Go to the last `}` and  press <kbd>F9</kbd> to do that.

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
} // <--- Set a breakpoint on this line (Press F9)
```