# console program exits

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

I have the following console program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;


cout<<"Enter a";
cin>>a;

cout<<"Enter b";
cin>>b;

int result = a*b;

cout<<"You entered"<<a<<"and you entered"<<b<<"Their product is"<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Once i run the program,it accepts the input but exits before i can have a look at the results.What do i need to do for the program not to exit before i can take a look at the results?.

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: You can always look at the results. Just capture the output or run it from existing console or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding `system ("pause");` before `return 0;` statement?

Comment: Build issues:'system' was not declared in this scope

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>` will declare `system` for you. But it would be better to find out how to make your environment keep the console open after the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, you've already calculated the value of `result` before you've gotten your input for `a` and `b`, so the value of `result` will either be `0` if your compiler assembles code that zero-initializes any variables declared on the stack, or will just be some random value.  In fact, you really don't need to even declare `result` ... you can calculate it's value in the `cout` statement.  So you can adjust your last line so it looks like this:

```
cout << "You entered" << a <<"and you entered"<< b 
     << "Their product is" << (a*b) << endl;
```

To stop the program from exiting, you can grab another `char` from `stdin`.  So you can do the following:

```
cout << "Press any key to exit..." << endl;
char extra;
cin >> extra;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getche() ,getch() or any character based input function.

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int result = a*b;

cout<<"Enter a";
cin>>a;

cout<<"Enter b";
cin>>b;

cout<<"You entered"<<a<<"and you entered"<<b<<"Their product is"<<result<<endl;
getch(); //use this.It would wait for  a character to input.
return 0;
}
```

And generally we use Enter to exit the program whose ASCII value is fetched by it .But since it is of no use to us not storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask for more feedback

```
cout<<"You entered"<<a<<"and you entered"<<b<<"Their product is"<<result<<endl;

char stop;
cin >> stop;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Windows:**

```
//1
    system ("pause");
//2
    #include<conio.h>
    _getch();
```

**.NET (Windows):**

```
System::Console::ReadLine();
```

**Overall:**

```
    #include <cstdlib.h>
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: I've no idea what `<conio.h>` is (or indeed `_getch`), but I'm guessing that also only works on Windows. In Standard C++, you want `getchar()` from `<cstdio>` or `cin.get()` from `<iostream>`.

Comment: @Secko: Not in my version it doesn't. The standard functions will work on any conforming compiler.

Comment: Hmm, it appears that it is so. However, it works on my machine with gcc.

Comment: Also, in C++ you should get `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `<cstdlib>`, not the deprecated C header; and you don't need a return statement at the end of `main` at all.

Comment: @Mike: Right, I got used to writing C so there you go, and the return was just a demonstration for him to know where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use getch() from conio.h when I'm on Windows, but that's not quite portable :/