# C output is not displaying (newbie to C)

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors

I am new to C and writing a simple program to display the byte representation of data. When I compile, the Command Prompt screen flashes for 1/2 a second and disappears. In simpler words, the output doesn't show up. Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typdef unsigned char* pointer;

void show_int(int);
void show_bytes(pointer, int);
int main()
{
show_int(100);
}

void show_int(int x)
{
show_bytes((ponter) &x, sizeof(int));
}

void show_bytes(pointer start, int len)
{ 
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
    printf("0x%p\t0x%.2x\n", start + i, start[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately

Comment: That was helpful too. Ad you're that pi-guy if I am not wrong.

Comment: Yep, you are correct. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program likely is displaying your output, then quickly exiting. You'll want to delay before exiting. If you're on Windows, use Sleep(milliseconds); if you're on Unix, use sleep(seconds). Note not only the different units, but the different capitalization.

Comment: Thanks! I had to `#include <Windows.h>` to make `Sleep(..)` work and that seems silly (I'll be careful to call it that because I am new to C) since I am working on a Windows machine already

Comment: Since you're using the C runtime for input/output, you could add call to getchar() at the end of main to prevent the program from ending before you've seen the output.  Press Enter/Return to end.

Answer (score 1):

```
show_bytes((ponter) &x, sizeof(int));
```

I guess that shall be `(pointer)` instead?

Follow Akroy's advice too. Unless you're using an IDE like CodeBlocks or something so.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, `show_bytes((ponter) &x, sizeof(int));` is right!

secondary, I think this question is that the output box disappear quickly on Windows console, if I am right, you can run your program in `cmd`.

For example, your program is in `d:\project\test.exe`

```
start -> run -> cmd ->
```

Step 1: change dir to your work place,

```
cmd:\ cd /d d:\project\
```

Step 2: execute it

```
cmd:\test.exe
```

or you can execute it directly with full path: `cmd:\d:\project\test.exe`.