# Console application instantly exits in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

I'm working with c++ and when I run my console program, it instantly exits. I can't read input from in my main method/set breakpoints because the main method is defined in another library.

So, I'm asking how can I prevent the console application from exiting by using a setting in visual studio?

Comment: "the main method is defined in another library." - Huh? How does that work?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm trying to use boost unit testing, it has it's own main method.

Comment: so it also doesn't break if you set breakpoints in your code? then it's most probably not running your code!

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+F5`? It should stop your console at the end of execution.

Comment: @Archie Ctrl+F5 works! Answer so I can accept your answer.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2529803/220636)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running with `Ctrl+F5`. This will stop the console at the end of the execution.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly you can't read the *output* of your program because console closes immediately. To prevent this you can call `system("pause");` just before returning from main.

```
int main()
{
    // processing...
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get a chance to call methods before the main, without resorting to hacks.

Comment: @ProgrammerAtWork: What hacks are you talking about? You should call this method INSIDE main (of course!) BEFORE returning from it.

Comment: I don't have a main method, the main method of a header that is included in my project is called.