# C++ Terminal Closes on Enter

Tags: c++, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

Forgive me for my rather extreme newbie-ness in the field of C++ but here goes. :)

When I run say for example this code in a terminal:

```
int g;
cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
cin >> g;
cout << "The value you entered is " << g;
```

...to you C++ experts out there, obviously this accepts a value from the user's input and then displays in the output. However, right after I "submit" my input and click enter, I see the output for a mere millisecond and then the terminal closes. Anyway I could stop the terminal from closing so I could actually have a chance to see the result?

I'm using Visual Studio on Windows 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `cin.get()` after the `cout`. Then hit return to continue when you are ready.

Comment: Yeah, IDEs still suck after all these years. Sigh. If you happen to be on Visual Studio, use Ctrl+F5 instead of F5 to run your program.

Comment: Or use a breakpoint like a normal person

Comment: If you are not using the debugger you can do what I have done for the last 20+ years. Open a console window and run your application from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working on Windows, you can add the line system("pause"); at the end of the program.
Or cin.get() if on Linux

Comment: system("pause'); works great. Just seems a little weird that Visual Studio does this with their terminal

Comment: Prefer `cin.ignore(10000, '\n');` to `cin.get()`.  It works on both platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're using. For Windows it is common to use a breakpoint (`__debugbreak`) but for Unix people usually just run it in an existing terminal which does not close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of OS do you use, but the function is similary

start a terminal in Linux oder a Commandline in Windows.
Switch with the command "cd" to the directory where the Program lies.

Linux:

./myProgram

Windows

myProgram

The Terminal which you started wouldn't be closed ;)