# The output console immediately closes upon display using user prompted input file

Tags: c++, io, ifstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

I'm using fstream to gather an input file from the user. Unfortunately, the console only displays briefly.

```
string filename;
cout << "input file" << endl ;

getline(cin,filename);

ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open(filename);

char file_character ;
int counter = 0;

while (inputfile>> file_character) {

    inputfile.get(file_character);
    cout << file_character;

    //not what I'm totally doing but instead a quick example
    if (file_character == 'a')
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
cout << counter << endl;
inputfile.close();
return 0;
```

I need to read every letter from the input file and do a number of checks on each of these characters. Why won't my console stay open?

Comment: Are you using Windows, by any chance ?

Comment: You're never checking anything. If *you* can't be bothered, how should *we* figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using windows, the console closes as the program exits.

append `system("Pause");` at the end of your program and it will prompt for a key to be pressed before exiting.

An universal solution (which would work on any system), is to read a char from the user using `std::getchar();` in place of windows exclusive `system("pause");`

Answer (score 1):

You can try launching your program from the console. Alternatively, you can pause your program before exiting `main`: for example, you can wait for user to enter a character, or set a time delay for a couple of seconds.

By the way, you have a bug in your program. `while (inputfile >> file_character)` already reads character into the variable, so when you go to `inputfile.get(file_character)` you read again and thus lose half of your input.