# C++ Help. Can not find command for wait till type

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b = 10, c;
    int age = 23;
    float average;
    char gender = 'm';
    bool isit = true;

    average = 22.45;

    cout << age << endl << average << endl << gender << endl << isit;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know but I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio for C++ I don't know if it has something to do with the settings but when I build and run it then command prompt window disrepair right away.

Comment: At the top I put #include <iostream>

Comment: Check: [Replicated ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the end:

```
cin.get();
```

It will wait for a user input.

Comment: Some explanation would be great

Comment: @dreadblood Your are welcome. Feel free to mark my answer as correct one. :)