# C executable returns immediately

Tags: c, gcc

I installed the GCC compiler to write some C code, but when I navigate to the directory, and use the command `gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c` It makes an executable on my desktop like normal, but when I run it, the executable closes immediately

I don't think that the code is the problem, but it's a possibility.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error???

Comment: There is no error, I use the gcc -o command in command prompt and when I get to run the executable, it crashes as soon as I open it

Comment: What does "crashes" mean????

Comment: There is no error message, I have helloworld.c on my desktop and I used the command in my question

Comment: What is the symptom of that crash? A system message, a hang, or shut down? Even the tiniest clue could help. *"Joe: A man's life in these parts often depends on a mere scrap of information."*

Comment: @JordanM.Baron Try adding the simply line `getchar()`to your file, and see if the command prompt then waits for a keypress.  I don't think it is actually crashing, rather exiting after quickly printing out the text.

Comment: How exactly do you run the executable? If you double-click on it from an explorer window, it will open a new window for the output, run and complete, and then the OS will close the window, perhaps before you see it. Try running it from a command prompt.

Comment: BTW, both the code and the compiler command look ok. (I suggest `int main(void)` rather than `int main()`, but that's a trivial issue that has nothing to do with what you're asking about.)

Comment: I don't understand why I am receiving downvotes, but ok.

Comment: Not me, but perhaps the DV is because you are presenting a properly working program as a "crash" without saying how that manifests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed this line `getchar()` in your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

***Note:*** Though, this is not the fix as @Keith Thompson [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38546814/6290553) in the other answer. Instead, this is a way where you can force the program from exiting until it waits for a keypress before the console window exits.

---

**Another way** (without using `getchar()`)

Open the **Command Prompt** (`cmd.exe`), and navigate to the program's directory and run your program from there. You'll find that the window doesn't disappears anymore, rather it stays open.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Comment: Using `<conio.h>` is unnecessary here...the code would be more portable without it.  **Edit:** Much better now ;)

Comment: @iRove thanks for notifying, removed it :)

Comment: I suggest that adding a call to `getchar()` is a workaround, not a fix. The real problem is that Windows has poor support for running command-line programs. Running the program from a command prompt is another solution.

Comment: If this is run from the command line, it will unnecessarily wait for input and the user may not know why. I only use getchar() for small quick and dirty programs that test something and for which I don't want to open a command line and navigate to the directory, etc.etc.

Comment: @KeithThompson fully agreed to what you've said :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Windows has poor support for running non-GUI programs.

A common way to run a program under Windows is to double-click the executable from an explorer window. For a program like yours that just prints to standard output, this will open a new window for the program's output, the program will run and quickly finish, and Windows will immediately close the window, perhaps before you have a chance to see it.

A common workaround is to add something to the end of your program, such as a call to `getchar()`, to cause the program to wait for input.

Another solution is to run the program from a command prompt. Its output will then appear in the current window rather than in a temporary one, and you'll see the program's output followed by a new prompt. If you run it that way, and added `getchar()` is unnecessary, and will make the program wait for input before terminating.

The Windows OS emphasizes GUI programs rather than programs that use plain text input and output. C was developed in a different kind of environment (though of course implementations of C for Windows support graphical operations).