# Clion Console doesn't show output

Tags: c++, clion

Clion Console doesn't show output on `Run`. But, when I try to `Debug` the output is shown in a separate window. How to make the output appear in Clion's built-in console on Run?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seeing the relevant code might help to answer this.

Comment: this problem appears for all print statements for example this code:
`#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @RihamHazem: The output console doesn't even show up at all on `Run`? Did you try to add some input function like `getchar()` before `return` statement? There are IDEs that don't pause the output window automatically so you have to put the pause yourself to make it stop. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately