# How do I stop the terminal from closing in C++ after the first std::cin?

Tags: c++, terminal, window, windows-10

I am taking a beginner's C++ class. At home, I was trying to duplicate a BMI calculator using std::cin to get data and std::cout to ask questions when I ran into a problem. The terminal would close whenever I pressed enter after typing the first std::cin. It was working fine in class, could somebody tell me what's going on?

Comment: Please [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48370471/edit) the relevant code as a [mcve].

Comment: If you have a debugger, just add a breakpoint right before `return 0;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

When you run code, it goes line-by-line and executes it. Because your code got to the last line, it stopped, and closed the terminal. I recommend either using a `while` loop or another `std::cin >>` at the end.

Comment: If you call your program from a terminal you wont have that problem, but you can use getchar(); to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you run the program as a standalone executable it will close the terminal once it is finished. You can halt the execution at the end using a function like `system("PAUSE")` on Windows/DOS, or something that requests input like `std::cin.get()` at the end if you need your code to be cross-platform. This will wait for some input so you can see the output of the program and then you can exit it by typing some input.

Comment: `system("PAUSE");` is a Windows/DOS specific hack, not a general cross-platform solution. Also; using `system` in the first place is horrible; have fun with all the nasty security issues.

Comment: Yes, I stated that OP can use this if on windows, I will add DOS. Also the question is tagged with `windows`, so I find this appropriate.

Comment: The CRT's `system` function doesn't use CMD's `/d` option to disable executing "AutoRun" commands, so it may end up running arbitrary commands. It's better to implement this yourself with `_write` and `_getch`, and not that complicated. Or just spawn an instance of CMD or PowerShell when exiting. By default, the shell will attach to the current console to keep it open.