# Button "Start Without Debbuging" doesn't do anything

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I wrote whole my program in c++ but when **I want to try it and start the program without debbuging it doesn't do anything.** I had same issue for more times but when I restarted visual studio the problem was fixed. But now I tried restarting VS, searching for help on the internet but I didn't find anything.

I am just begginer in VS so I don't know how should I fix it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the instructions to fix this for projects that start as an "empty project". This fixed the issue for me.

"Please right-click your project name and go to Properties page, please expand Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System, please select Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) in SubSystem dropdown. Because, by default, the Empty project does not specify it."

You can also refer this link, might help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834914/693636

Answer (score 0):

VS does not automatically run whatever is in your code window. You must go to Solution Explorer and identify which code to run by right clicking and setting it as the startup file.

[image]