# How to stop .exe file from closing immediately?

Tags: rust

I am trying to run the rust executable file but it kept closing immediately.

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::with_capacity(100);
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    let v: Vec<i32> = input
        .trim()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|x| x.trim().parse().unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

This is the program I am trying to run. This is a simple program that accepts numbers from a user from command line and then stores those numbers in a vector and then prints the vector. But the executable closes immediately after I enter all the numbers.

I was wondering if rust had a getchar() function like in c++ to stop the executable from closing immediately.

I am facing a problem similar to the one faced by the user who asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately) in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `getchar` is not for stopping the executable from closing directly. It is for reading a char. It happens to be a blocking call, so of course it is blocked there. You already used a tool like that, `read_line`:

```rust
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::with_capacity(100);
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
    let v: Vec<i32> = input
        .trim()
        .split_whitespace()
        .map(|x| x.trim().parse().unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", v);
    stdin().read_line(&mut input).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I don't want to mutate the input string.

Comment: @Aditya, well...just create another string or buffer...Also if it is windows, in the question you post you have some solutions calling some system calls. But it would probably be more convoluted...

Comment: `read_line(&mut String::new())` if you don't need the string.