Why are "return 0" and "cin.get()" not working to keep the terminal open?
I just started to learn C++ and learn the basic of it. I follow the tutorial on YouTube but I got a problem with keeping the terminal window open.
It's been awhile since I installed VSCode and C++, and I started learning the basics, so I tried to write this:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello y'all" << endl;

    return 0;
}

When I run it, I expect it to not immediately close the window, but it won't work properly. So, I tried to use cin.get() and it worked as expected. Then I tried something more complex, like this:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int day;
    cout << "Insert Number: ";
    cin >> day;

    switch (day) {
        case 1: cout << "Monday"; break;
        case 2: cout << "Tuesday"; break;
        case 3: cout << "Wednesday"; break;
        case 4: cout << "Thursday"; break;
        case 5: cout << "Friday"; break;
        case 6: cout << "Saturday"; break;
        case 7: cout << "Sunday"; break;
        default: cout << "Input Invalid!"; break;
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

}

1 cin.get() is not working again. It works properly when I double it.
Is there something wrong with my VSCode or my terminal?
I have installed Python before C++, so maybe the installations collide with each other?

Tell us your operating system, your compiler, and what commands / keystrokes / menu clicks you use to compile and run your program.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately

Related to your problem, though not exact: Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?

The terminal window closes when there is no console programs running in it. If the terminal is created when your program begins, then the window will close when your program exits (if it doesn't spawn other console apps). That is what is happening in your 1st example.
Your 2nd example is encountering a variation of Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction? Your call to cin >> day is not reading the \n character at the end of the user's input when they type ENTER. The following call to cin.get() reads the \n and exits immediately.  That is why you need another call to cin.get() to wait for the user to type in something again, such as another ENTER.

thanks, for the second one I have understood, but I still don't know how to solve the first problem

Using cin.get()  a second time is kludge and (in more complicated scenarios, such as reading more than one value of different types using cin >> ...) still won't necessarily work.   Better to read using cin >> ....  to read everything (e.g.  use cin >> some_char instead of cin.get()).   Generally, it is necessary to avoid avoid mixing styles of input - so read EVERYTHING from a stream using the same method e.g. cin >> ...   or std::getline()  [and parse the string] or cin.get() [and interpret the stream of characters].

@RidvanIvan You "solve" both problems by acknowledging that you are building command line applications. These are intended to be run from the command line. I.e., you open a terminal, then run the program by typing their name, and the terminal will stay open. That VS Code does something else with your program (open a terminal on the fly) is the problem of VS Code, not with your program. If you remove the superfluous cin.get() calls, then your programs are super perfect.

@RidvanIvan there is nothing to solve for the 1st example, because it is not broken to begin with. It is behaving correctly. If your program creates a new terminal, then the terminal is closed when the program exits. If the program is run in an existing terminal, then the terminal stays open after the program exits. This is normal behavior for a console program.

@Peter changing cin.get() to cin >> ... doesn't address the issue of leaving behind unread data in the input buffer. If the input is line-based to begin with (which is usually the case), then it is usually best to use std::getline() to read it, andstd::istringstream to parse it
