C++ EXE appears not to run outside of Visual Studio
I'm having trouble getting a simple exe to run... outside of Visual Studio. (I have looked at previously posted questions that are phrased similarly but turn out to be more complex situations involving missing libraries.)
In MS Visual Studio 2022 I can add a new Console project to my "Solution".
I leave the default "Hello World" sample code as is.
Within Visual Studio, I can run the program with debug mode chosen and pressing either the solid green or hollow green buttons... a console window will be spawned with the appropriate program output displayed inside it.
Still within Visual Studio, I can run the program with release mode chosen and pressing either the solid green or hollow green buttons... a console window will be spawned with the appropriate program output displayed inside it.
In release mode, a .exe is created in the x64/release folder designated for such things.
Double clicking on the .exe has no effect. No console window is spawned.
If i merely "Build" the project in Visual Studio, that also creates a .exe file.
However that result also will not run if double-clicked on.
Here is typical VS output from the build. No errors are noted.
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication2, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Generating code
1>0 of 11 functions ( 0.0%) were compiled, the rest were copied from previous compilation.
1>  0 functions were new in current compilation
1>  0 functions had inline decision re-evaluated but remain unchanged
1>Finished generating code
1>ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj -> E:\_BI_Projects\CplusPlus_take5\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication2.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 6:34 PM and took 00.229 seconds ==========

What needs to be done to create a working EXE in this simple default situation?

You need to remember that your compiled program still needs your compilers runtime environment to be able to run. So you always need to ship your compilers runtime along with your program. Executables don't exist in a vacuum.

Can you run your exe from the command line?  (Open a Command Prompt, cd to the directory and execute the program)

You can also try adding some input at the end of your program so that the console window will be held open while input is pending. For example: std::cout << "Press Enter to continue..."; std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s);  This should allow you to just double-click the .exe name in Windows Explorer, without opening a console window first.

Most likely a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately

You need a deployment/package created to contain all dependencies that come naturally with the IDE

This question is similar to: How to stop C++ console application from exiting immediately?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Since you created a console application, you must run it from a command window to see the result.
If you click on the executable in File Explorer, then the console window opens, the program output is written to it, and the window closes immediately. "Hello, world" program runs too fast for you to notice the window appearing for a fraction of a second.
