# Debugging C# on the command line: ">"-character

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, command-line-arguments

I'm creating a small commandline tool for a customer and trying to verify its output. The output is been written to the commandline itself. Since its rather a huge file that's been used as an input file and thus a huge out to write to the commandline, I wanted the output to redirect to a file.
Usually I use use commandline arguments like so to redirect the output to a file:

```
a.exe ./input.txt > ./ouput.txt
```

However, in my program, I try to verify the input:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 1)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    ...
```

And `args` now is:

```
args[0] = ./input.txt
args[1] = >
args[2] = ./ouput.txt
```

Honestly I personally still expect only one argument, since the file is been created and thus the shell does understand what I mean. So... what am I doing wrong? Should I use `args` or something else?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guess you're gonna have to change your verification code.

Comment: Try to add parenthesis, like this:

(a.exe ./input.txt) > ./ouput.txt

Comment: For me, it works as expected. May you also try `a.exe ./input.txt>./ouput.txt` (without spaces)?

Comment: `args.Length` should be 1 as you expect. How are you invoking your tool? Are you typing the commandline in a shell?

Comment: Dan-o: I thought about using external libraries instead (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491595/best-way-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-c) but for such a simple thing I just did not want to bother. It also would not make anything more simple in my case.
Alexandre: Can't do that in VS2012, can I?
AlexFilipovici: That would have worked if I did not use any quotes around my file names ;-)
Thanks anyways!

Comment: @user2266486 I'm debugging in VS2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing the arguments through Visual Studio? It will only work if you untick **Enable the Visual Studio hosting process**.

[image]

Image and explanation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289400/324260).

Comment: I did look for an answer, but did not find that article. Thanks!