# Wait for key when my console app ends, no matter how it was launched

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application, wait

Since I code in Visual Studio (2015), there are three main ways to launch my app:

1. Pressing F5 in VS ("Start debugging")
2. Pressing Ctrl+F5 in VS ("Start without debugging")
3. Run the app from outside VS

With methods 1 and 3 the app window closes when the app ends execution. With method 2 it waits for any key before closing.

**How do I make it wait for any key in all 3 cases?** I use all 3 launching methods.

I could detect if I'm in case 2, and if not, call `Console.ReadKey()`. But how to detect it?

I can detect case 1 by checking `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`. But I can't differentiate between cases 2 and 3.

I tried the following to differentiate between those two cases but in both cases the result is `false`:

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
string moduleName = currentProcess.MainModule.ModuleName;
bool isLaunchedFromVS = moduleName.Contains(".vshost");
```

**Note:** Another approach would be to call `ReadKey` in all cases, but then I would need to know how to disable the built-in keywait of case 2. And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897736/avoiding-press-any-key-to-continue-when-running-console-application-from-visua) this isn't possible.

**Related question:**
[Check if application was started from within Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101806/check-if-application-was-started-from-within-visual-studio) - but it doesn't ask how to differentiate between cases 2 and 3.

Comment: Why not wait for a character input in ALL cases  and force close your program?

Comment: @FirstStep: But wait for only *one* character input.

Comment: Use `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` for _one_ char read from console. Then maybe "_Do you want to exit the program? Y/N_" and force close your app if `Y`.. Or something like that.

Comment: @FirstStep OP wants to know if it is possible to avoid getting 2 prompts in case 2: one from the program and one that VS adds automatically.

Comment: @BJMyers Right but not if he force close the app no?

Comment: @FirstStep: By force close you mean click the X button in the top right of the window? That's not very nice, the button is very small and I have to remember to do it this way.

Comment: No @StefanMonov I meant this: [**Command to close an application of console?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682408/command-to-close-an-application-of-console)

Comment: @FirstStep: Calling Environment.Exit(0) doesn't prevent the extra keywait.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect if "Press any key to continue . . ." will be displayed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458932/how-can-i-detect-if-press-any-key-to-continue-will-be-displayed)