# Why do we assign child class object to parent class reference variable?

Tags: c#

I have the following code.

```
public class Parent
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Parent Method");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public new void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Child Method");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Child C = new Child();
        C.Print();
    }
}
```

If I run this code, I get the result "Child Method"
But if I do the following, why do I get the result "Parent Method"?

```
public class Parent
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Parent Method");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public new void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Child Method");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Parent P = new Child();   // The only difference is this.
        P.Print();
    }
}
```

The only difference is as below

```
Child C = new Child();   
Parent P = new Child();
```

I thought `new Child()` means that we create the instance of `Child` class. 
And I thought both, `C` and `P`, are just object reference variables that hold the location of instance of `Child` class.
Can you correct me if I'm wrong or tell me if I miss something because I don't understand why in the above cases I get different results?

Comment: Because you are hiding methods, not overriding them. When you write P.Print, the compiler can only call the parents print method, not the hidden child method.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717570/why-does-calling-a-method-in-my-derived-class-call-the-base-class-method

Comment: As an aside, I recommend avoiding method hiding unless you legitimately need it.  It tends to make code harder to maintain.  Quoting Eric Lippert's [Method Hiding Apologia](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia.aspx), "It lets derived types appear to break the contracts of base types. If a derived type D hides a method M on base class B because D.M does something different than B.M, shouldn't it have a different name?"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's because you've redeclared the `Print` method in `Child`. So at compile time, `P.Print()` resolves to `Parent.Print`, but `C.Print()` resolves to `Child.Print()`. If you had a virtual method which was *overridden* in `Child` instead, they'd both print "Child Method":

```
public class Parent
{
    // Declare this as virtual, allowing it to be overridden in
    // derived classes. The implementation will depend on the
    // execution-time type of the object it's called on.
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Parent Method");
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    // Override Parent.Print, so if Print is called on a reference
    // with compile-time type of Parent, but at execution it
    // refers to a Child, this implementation will be executed.
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Child Method");
    }
}
```

Related:

- [What's the difference between `override` and `new`?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-override-code-and-code-new-code.aspx) (C# FAQ entry on MSDN - turns out to have been written by me, but I'd forgotten!)
- [Knowing when to use the `override` and `new` keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) (MSDN)

Answer (score 10):

Here is what happens under the hood

```
Child C = new Child();
C.Print();
```

Because you are hiding methods, not overriding them. so Print method in Parent is hidden and Child.Print() is invoked.

[image]

```
 Parent P = new Child();   // The only difference is this.
 P.Print();
```

This (New Child()) will be called on a Parent type Reference.

[image]

if you try this one, Parent type reference will be casted to Child type. Henceforth Child.Print() is invoked.

```
Parent P = new Child(); 
((Child)P).Print();
```

[image]

output will be: **Child Method**

Comment: Thank you for the answer but could you tell me what they are??

Comment: @JCronin they are CIL. CIL is a low level language. basically when you compile your code, it will be compiled into intermediate language (IL) it is also called MSIL ( Microsoft Intermediate Language). you can see IL code using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx
BTW, I used LINQPad to get the IL code. you can check it here https://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 5):

Since the `Print` method is not `virtual`, the compiler will not emit code to tell the CLR to invoke the method according to the actual runtime type.

So, when your variable is referred as `Child`, `Child.Print` would be invoked. But, when you're referring to it as `Parent`, `Parent.Print` would be used.

The use of the `new` keyword here is only meant for *shadowing*, to tell the compiler that the child method is indeed *hiding* the parent method and not overriding it, but has no effect otherwise.

Comment: I never understood this line - "Child method is indeed hiding the parent method". If so, why the parent method is invoked when we don't override it. => Base b = new Child(). If the method is hidden by child then it should not have been called.

Answer (score 1):

JCronin, you are casting to the Parent with Parent P = new Child(). To get the Child class behavior, you have to either cast it back to a Child (var x = (Child)P) or create the Child instance instance (Child P = new Child()).

See [Downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting)

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared the type of `P` to be `Parent`.  When you assign a `Child` to it, it will get cast to that type.