# c#: flow of control when calling an inherited base method, which inturn calls a base virtual method which is set as new in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

disclaimer: i am totally newbie to this world of coding!
in my course on learning c#, i read this article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords.

code:

```
public class Car
{
    public void DescribeCar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car: Four wheels and an engine.");
        ShowDetails();
    }

    public virtual void ShowDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Car: Standard transportation.");
    }
}

public class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
    public new void ShowDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens up.");
    }
}

ConvertibleCar myCC = new ConvertibleCar();
myCC.DescribeCar();
myCC.ShowDetails();

//Output
Car: Four wheels and an engine.
Car: Standard transportation.
ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens
```

Question: i expect with my understanding i should get "ConvertibleCar: A roof than opens" in my second and third line of output.
what is it different when calling ShowDetails directly on the derived class, and from within a method in the base class.
PS: the  showdetials is set at new in the derived class.

Comment: i guess i just found now, a similar question, i am going through it now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717570/why-does-calling-a-method-in-my-derived-class-call-the-base-class-method

Comment: no that didnt help me.

Comment: @Sweeper Rainman both of your feedback helped me get this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your expected output, use `override` in place of `new`:

```
public override void ShowDetails()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens up.");
}
```

If you use `new`, you *shadowed* the `ShowDetails` method in the base class. This means that the derived class implementation will only be used when you call the method from a derived class variable.

`override` does something different. If `ShowDetails` is overridden, then the derived class implementation will always be used as long as the object's underlying type is the derived class, no matter the type of the variable.

This explains why the second line of output is different. The second line is produced from this line:

```
public void DescribeCar()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Car: Four wheels and an engine.");
    ShowDetails(); <--------
}
```

`ShowDetails` means `this.ShowDetails`. `this` is of type `Car` but actually refers to an object of `ConvertibleCar`. Since `ShowDetails` is shadowed, it calls the implementation of `Car` (because `this` is of type `Car`!)

Comment: "ShowDetails means this.ShowDetails. this is of type Car but actually refers to an object of ConvertibleCar. Since ShowDetails is shadowed, it calls the implementation of Car (because this is of type Car!)" :

This explanation gives a bit more clarity, thank you.

but when i instantiate ConvertibleCar object, wont the ShowDetails() method, which it received by inheritance be pointing to the derived classes implimentation?.

i may be not getting some basics clear on how the objects are really instantiated cand referred/used in inheritance scenarios.

Comment: @TechieSahal Yes it does point to the derived class implementation. That's why you get the `ConvertibleCar`'s implementation for the third line of output. Think of it like this: when you create a new `ConvertibleCar`, the object has two `ShowDetails` method. One is the `Car`'s implementation, the other is the `ConvertibleCar`'s implementation. When the type is `ConvertibleCar`, the `Car` implementation is hidden. When the type is `Car`, the `ConvertibleCar` implementation is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Because with `new` you effectively shadowed `ShowDetails` (in fact, in VB.NET there's a [Shadows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shadows) keyword for this). Moreover, with `new` you can make `ShadowDetails` a property!

Let's create two classes: Base and Derived:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual int GetInt()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public new int GetInt()
    {
        return 11;
    }
}
```

Now, let's test them:

```
Base b;
Derived d;
int x;

b = new Derived();
d = new Derived();

x = b.GetInt(); // x = 10 [Base.GetInt()]
x = d.GetInt(); // x = 11 [Derived.GetInt()]
```

As you see, although `b` is assigned Derived, it still refers to `Base`.

But let's do something completely different - let's turn method into a property!

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public new int GetInt
    {
        get { return 11; }
    }
}
```

Now when we run previous test code we will see that `x = 10`:

```
x = d.GetInt(); // x = 10
```

But, wait, we don't have `GetInt()` method in `Derived` class! Why the code is compiled? It's simple - because we shadowed GetInt() method with `GetInt` property, now `GetInt()` is called from `Base`! To confuse things more, the IntelliSense doesn't show `GetInt()` method on `d` variable, but the compiler is satisfied. To get 11, you need to call property:

```
x = d.GetInt;
```

You can also turn `GetInt()` method into delegate:

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public new delegate int GetInt();
}
```

and use it:

```
Derived.GetInt getIntDelegate = () => 12;
Console.WriteLine(getIntDelegate()); // Prints 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword used for the hiding base member/method. So

```
public new void ShowDetails()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens up.");
}
```

`ShowDetails` method is a `new` method for `ConvertibleCar` class and the base class `ShowDetails` method is completely different and it is not in the inheretance chain. Imagine that, you could define the method name like `ShowDetails2` in the `ConvertibleCar` class. It would be same case.

Also, if you use the override `keyword` instead of `new`, the `ConvertibleCar` class would override the `ShowDetails` method.

```
public class ConvertibleCar : Car
{
    public override void ShowDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens up.");
    }
}
```

And output would be;

```
Car: Four wheels and an engine.
ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens.
ConvertibleCar: A roof that opens.
```

Comment: wow! this platform is awsome. reponse recieved in 15 minutes!

thank you for the quick feedback, but i could not get it yet.

what i understood is: 
if you use new keyword for a method in a derived class, that method gets preference when using the instance of that derived class.
and here i am using the instance of ConvertibleCar and the variable type is also ConvertibleCar.

and only when the ShowDetails() is called within the inherited baseclass method Describecar() i have the imappropriate behaviousr.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As you see, "new" keyword hide the base class method.