# Automatically pause the console application in c#

Tags: c#, console

I know I can use `Console.ReadKey();` or `Console.ReadLine();` to wait for the user input.

I am following some video tutorials from [youTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAC325451207E3105)

There I notice that when the tutor writes some code like

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a basic C# tutorial");
```

He gets a message saying `Press any key to continue...`

So, I want to know how to get the above message without writing any code for displaying the message.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103402/how-does-vs-compile-console-applications-to-show-press-any-key-to-continue?rq=1

Comment: It's probably a WriteLine of "press any key" followed by a ReadKey...

Comment: What you describe in the question does not match reality.

Comment: please watch the first video on the link provided to help understand my problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run without debugging sounds like what you want. Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only used when you are debugging it and wont be in what ever your final result that the user would see.