# Visual Studio 2015 Console app does not print anything

Tags: c#, console-application

I have been using Visual Studio 2015 Professional for quite some time now, primarily for WPF and Console based apps. Very recently I have noticed that my Console based apps just stopped printing anything to console.

To test this I wrote a very simple console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I was expecting the see a black console with the below statements:

```
Hello!!!
Press any key to continue...
```

I just see a black console with cursor blinking... nothing else.

My laptop is Windows 7 64 bit and the VS 2015 Pro is 32 bit. I run using **"Any CPU"** configuration. This issue is driving me nuts!

The interesting thing is, when I run in debug mode all I can see output printing on to console.

How do I get things printing back in console?

Comment: Are you running via Ctrl+F5?

Comment: None writes for you "Press any key to continue..." and waits for any key. You are in charge of what your code does

Comment: Include Console.ReadLine() after WriteLine() as the console window does not wait, it closes. You need to write Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue....") followed by Console.ReadLine()

Comment: @Chase:
Yes.
Ctrl+F5 :  does not show anything
F5: Printing shows all outputs to console

Comment: Try add Console.ReadKey();  after your Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..."); Console.ReadKey(true);` at the end. Programs do what you ask them to do, unless you explicitly say "wait for user input, then exit" it will exit immediately after running the last statement.

Comment: @Chase:  I tried that as well...no luck. The Ctrl+F5 just does not print anything.

@Steve/@Ron:  You do not have to print "Press any key to continue..." to see this. Console applicaions always show this in the end of your application.

Comment: @x86_64 the "Press any key to continue" being automatic is news to me, but I've not used 2015 much at all.  Reading your description/comments, are you saying that your output is coming out on the Command/Immediate panel of Visual Studio, rather than the visible shell?

Comment: @Mike:  Build my code in VS 2010, run it using Ctrl+F5, you will see the "Press..." in the end. 

This was always the case running your build from VS (Ctrl+F5): 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103402/how-does-vs-compile-console-applications-to-show-press-any-key-to-continue

Comment: @x86_64 I've been writing .NET applications since 1.0 came out (about 13 years ago) and C++/VB software much longer than that. I guarantee you that the "halting" is not automatic, and your own code proves it.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework doesn't do halting *for* you. You have to do it yourself, or your console will immediately close.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the framework does not do halting. I should have framed my question better. I was referring to running the application from Visual Studio using Ctrl+F5. That always shows "Press any key to continue...". Switching to VS 2015 I seem to be missing that. I always saw that feature in VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

@RonBeyer:
* Please use my above code in a simple console application

- Build it
- Run it as Ctrl + F5
- You will see this:

[Output from above console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqLtO.jpg)

I am able to see the above using VS2012 Professional but not usnig VS2015 Professional.

Thank you.
x86_64

Answer (score 0):

What kind of antivirus software you have - Avast?
I ran into the same problem with Console Application starting from VS2015.
I also noticed, that it creates a couple of processes, that can't be killed with Task Manager.

@MadDoctor5813 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215983/c-sharp-application-built-with-visual-studio-2015-refuses-to-start) ran into the same kind of problem and disabling antivirus (Avast in his and my case) solved to problem.

Avast usually shows a message, when blocking or checking VS projects, but this time it doesn't warn a user, so that's why it's not really obvious, what's going on.